# Rename reusable blocks shown in navigator

Tags: block-editor

I have a number of reusable blocks. In the block editor, when I popup the navigator, all those blocks are called "Reusable Block".

This makes editing a document difficult.

Is there a way to name those blocks, so they show a useful name in the navigator?

Answer (score 2):

Each Reusable Block can have a name.[image]

Comment: Yes but when you use it somewhere, the navigator shows "Reusable Block". Not its name.

Comment: You might have discovered a bug in WordPress. :)

Comment: Lol, can you confirm whether you also see that behavior, or is it just me? :) The navigator shows all my reusable blocks as "Reusable Block" - do you see that too?

Comment: This is what I see when I save the reusable block: http://screenshot.how/OieLlw    and this is what I see when I only hover over it: http://screenshot.how/e45cbC   Therefore I think it may be a bug or a negligence. It should say the name of the block on hover as well.

Comment: Yes me too. And in the navigation popup `shift+alt+o` it only shows "Reusable Block".